# Drill down using xslt in a while loop?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to make a drill down report with xslt
I have this xml:

```
    <dbqueries>
    <dbquery id="pers">
        <rows>
            <row nb="1" name="walt" mgr="2" boss="0"/>
            <row nb="2" name="pete" mgr="4" boss="0"/>
            <row nb="2" name="marie" mgr="4" boss="0"/>
            <row nb="3" name="sven" mgr="4" boss="0"/>
            <row nb="4" name="mike" mgr="5" boss="1"/>
        </rows>
    </dbquery>
</dbqueries>
```

If I pick for example nb=1, I want the following result:

```
walt > pete > mike
```

and I stop with mike because mike is the boss (=1)

If I picked nb=3, then I want the following:

```
sven > mike
```

I thought to do in my xslt something with a template that is been recalling till boss="1"

but I am not sure how I have to do that. Can someone help me our give me another possibility to get the result I want?

Comment: "*If I pick for example nb=1*" How exactly will you do the picking? -- P.S. Your XML is not well-formed.

Comment: I will pick nb=1 in the parameter of the url. The XML is not well-formatted because I just picked what was necessary for my question

Comment: You have two rows with the `nb` attribute set to `2`. Is that correct? If so, it would mean that poor old "walt" had two managers; "pete" and "maria"!

Comment: yes indeed :-) and we take the first in the row

Comment: What does "the first in the row" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:param name="nb" select="1"/>
<xsl:key name="row-by-nb" match="row" use="@nb" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('row-by-nb', $nb)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:if test="not(@boss=1)">
        <xsl:text> > </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('row-by-nb', @mgr)"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped a lot. Question: is there a difference if I was in XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @Bigjo No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an `xsl:key` to look up your `row` elements by the `nb` attribute

```
<xsl:key name="row_by_nb" match="row" use="@nb" />
```

Assuming you are passing the nb value in as a parameter, you would start off by selecting the relevant row using the key

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('row_by_nb', $nb)" />
```

Then, in the template matching `row` you could simply output their name. Then, you could test to see if they had a manager, if so, you would recursively call the template using the key

```
<xsl:if test="key('row_by_nb', @mgr)[1]">
    <xsl:text> > </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('row_by_nb', @mgr)[1]" />
</xsl:if>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output output="text" />

   <xsl:param name="nb" select="'1'" />
   <xsl:key name="row_by_nb" match="row" use="@nb" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('row_by_nb', $nb)" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="row">
      <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
      <xsl:if test="key('row_by_nb', @mgr)[1]">
          <xsl:text> > </xsl:text>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('row_by_nb', @mgr)[1]" />
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or maybe this, which avoids the repeated use of the key

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output output="text" />

   <xsl:param name="nb" select="'1'" />
   <xsl:key name="row_by_nb" match="row" use="@nb" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('row_by_nb', $nb)" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="row">
      <xsl:param name="separator" select="''" />

      <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />
      <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('row_by_nb', @mgr)[1]">
          <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="' > '" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```